# Unterstanding Java PrintInlining Parameter

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot

I'm running a Java Program with following parameter:

-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintInlining

I'm getting this output:

```
@ 83   java.util.LinkedList::getFirst (22 bytes)
    @ 13  java/util/NoSuchElementException::<init> (not loaded)   not inlineable
```

What does this exactly mean?

Does it mean, that the code of getFirst is inlined, and the exception is not inlined?

Or does it mean, getFirst and the exception are both not inlined?

Here is the code of: getFirst

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.getFirst%28%29

Same question here:

```
@ 99   java.util.LinkedList::peek (18 bytes)
```

Is it inlined?

http://planet.jboss.org/post/inline_all_the_things

On this link, there is a suffix "inline (hot)".
In my example, there is no suffix. What does this mean?

Comment: Cold you add your code? It looks like you want get element, which is not there ( empty collections, etc)

Answer (score 1):

In the code for `LinkedList::getFirst`, you'll see it constructs a `NoSuchElementException`. So the VM tries to inline the call.

However, the seems to be a rule that exception initialisers are not inlined - in my PrintInlining logs, Oracle JDK 8 explicitly annotates these lines like this:

```
@ 11   java.lang.NullPointerException::<init> (6 bytes)   don't inline Throwable constructors
```